# How to get gender and age by faceId or thumbnailId using Azure FaceAPI

Tags: azure, face-api

I am able to get the faces in a video using the video indexer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/video-indexer-output-json-v2#faces.

However, this does not contain the age or the gender attributes I need for my use case. Is there any way to get this information?

Comment: I notice that video indexer does not contain age and gender attributes. Maybe you can consider using https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236. It detects human faces in images and contains age and gender attributes. You can acquire frames from a video source and analyze the frames for implementing. This link of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoanalyzevideo_face for your reference.

Comment: Thanks Kiron, the reason I want to use the video indexer api is that it will find the number of unique faces in a video. If I do it frame by frame I will have to check this myself (which is very complex) . Also I don't understand why the thumbnail Id is provided if we can't use it.